# Entity Framework 6 Eager loading large object with many children and subchildren

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, eager-loading

I am migrating a project from lazy loading to eager loading.

I need to get a large object with all it's children, serialise it and send to front end's SPA app.

I built massive query, but it takes too much memory (as shown in VS's data diagnostic tools, the memory usage jumps by 200mb, the object itself is ~60KB when serialised to JSON )

```
Include(x => x.Privileges)
.Include(x => x.Team.Branch)
.Include(x => x.Equality)
.Include(x => x.AddressDetails).Include(x => x.ContactDetails)

.Include(x => x.EmployeeDetails.GeneralUnavailability)
.Include(x => x.EmployeeDetails.EligibilityDocuments.Select(z => z.Document.Priviliges))
.Include(x => x.EmployeeDetails.Position.PositionPayRuleExceptions).Include(x => x.EmployeeDetails.Position.PositionPayRuleExceptions.Select(z => z.PayRule)).Include(x => x.EmployeeDetails.Position.DefaultOffer)


.Include(x => x.TransportationMode.ProofOfLicence.Priviliges).Include(x => x.TransportationMode.ProofOfInsurance)

.Include(x => x.UserAcademicQualifications.Select(z => z.AcademicQualification)).Include(x => x.UserAcademicQualifications.Select(z => z.AcademicQualificationScan.Priviliges))

.Include(x => x.ProfessionalRegistrations.Select(z => z.Body)).Include(x => x.ProfessionalRegistrations.Select(z => z.ProfessionalRegistrationScan.Priviliges))
.Include(x => x.Unavailabilities.Select(z => z.AbsenceType)).Include(x => x.Unavailabilities.Select(z => z.Document.Priviliges))
.Where(x=>x.Id=1)
```

I am new to making queries with ef6...because I was using lazy loading until now. Is there a way to optimise it?

Priviliges is a list of Privilige model

Document,ProfessionalRegistrationScan,AcademicQualificationScan,ProofOfInsurance,ProofOfLicence  are using File model which has many to many relation Priviliges.

Thank you for your help

**UPDATE**

Tried using .AsNoTracking() as a test..and memory usage jumps by ~100mb with it.
Which is still kinda high for ~60kb object...

Comment: do you use .AsNoTracking()? also, with "too much memory" you mean the object is actually too big to fit into the memory, or is query execution too slow? if that's the case, keep in mind a query with many includes especially will take some time to be translated into SQL.

Comment: The query takes 200ms to execute, which is 10 times faster than with lazy loading. The object isn't that big in terms of size in MB. It just executing that query takes 200 MB of memory..as shown in VS's Data Diagnostic tools. Will .AsNoTracking() make the object detached? I also have places where I need to save changes back....

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I've ever seen `AsNoTracking` *increase* memory usage before...  It will definitely cause some issues if you try to modify the data and save it back later, though it is possible to work around them.

Comment: Is it possible to convert all of those include into some kind of inner join query to build up the big object?  I think, main memory usage comes from EF trying to generate the query automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So..the only optimisation I found ,which will keep track of entities is

```
app = db.Users.Include(x => x.Privileges)
     .Include(x => x.Team.Branch)
     .Include(x => x.Equality)
     .Include(x => x.AddressDetails)
     .Include(x => x.ContactDetails).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==3);

app = db.Users.Include(x => x.ApplicantDetails.ApplicantOffers.Select(z => z.Offer))
        .Include(x => x.ApplicantDetails.ApplicantOffers.Select(z => z.OfferDocument))
        .Include(x =>x.ApplicantDetails.AppliedPosition.PositionPayRuleExceptions)
       .Include(x => x.ApplicantDetails.AppliedPosition.DefaultOffer)
       .Include(x => x.ApplicantDetails.Branch.AddressDetails).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==3);
```

Basically, divide it all into chunks. It still less queries than Lazy loading.

**Update:**
Same thing works for ef.core . Just split it into chunks

Answer (score 3):

Well, the data is sort of the data. If you *actually* need all of that, then that might very well be the best you can do. Eager-loading and using `AsNoTracking` as you've done helps, obviously. There's really only a few more things you can look at:

1. If it's something you can "page", using `Skip` and `Take` can reduce the amount of data you have to retrieve all at once. You'll issue more queries during paging, obviously, but each individual query will be lighter, at least only happens based on a request from the user, versus always. For example, if they only care about the first page of results, then you never have to fetch all the rest of that data.
2. Make judicious use of `Select`. If you only need certain columns, then selecting only those columns into some other DTO class or an anoynous object will lighten the demands of the query.
3. Create a stored procedure. If you were to view the query generated by EF for something like this, it would likely be massive. EF does a relatively good job at optimizing queries, but with this many joins, it can't help but be huge. SQL Server, then, has to parse all of this SQL and come up with an execution plan before it can actually run the query and return the results. A stored procedure takes all this initial work out of the equation.
4. If you can't really optimize it further and you need all this data all at once, then really your only other option is to throw resources at your database. Make sure it has plenty of RAM, plenty of cores, a fast drive - preferably SSD, etc. Also make sure that the network between your web server and the database server is as fast as possible. Ideally, they should be on the same LAN. If you have to cross firewalls and such, that's going to slow down things dramatically.

Comment: Thank you. I will be looking into stored procedure option

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer, use Split in order to avoid all those joins that cause the code to run slow at the cost of sendding more queries to the DB but each requesting less data.

This way if you use async programming all the entities will be filled without the user noticing the delay.

Using the accepted answer result, just to this:

```
app = db.Users.Include(x => x.Privileges)
 .Include(x => x.Team.Branch)
 .Include(x => x.Equality)
 .Include(x => x.AddressDetails)
 .Include(x => x.ContactDetails).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==3)
 .Include(x => x.ApplicantDetails.ApplicantOffers.Select(z => z.Offer))
 .Include(x => x.ApplicantDetails.ApplicantOffers.Select(z => z.OfferDocument))
 .Include(x =>x.ApplicantDetails.AppliedPosition.PositionPayRuleExceptions)
 .Include(x => x.ApplicantDetails.AppliedPosition.DefaultOffer)
 .Include(x => x.ApplicantDetails.Branch.AddressDetails)
 .AsSplitQuery()
 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id==3);
```